# Installing LineageOS OTA update from the recovery manually

Tags: custom-roms, ota-update, rom-update, lineageos

I installed LineageOS on my OnePlus One, and today I got the latest nightly. The OTA update system downloaded the file, and I clicked install. However, it says

> Note: This feature requires a compatible recovery or you will have to install it manually.

Then it sends me to recovery and nothing happens.

Can I get some help as to how to update?

Comment: From the recovery, navigate to the folder where the update ZIP has been downloaded and install it.

Comment: Yeaa. I don't know where it downloaded to.  @DeathMaskSalesman

Comment: Is your recovery TWRP? I am using TWRP on my Redmi 1s, after downloading, by clicking on Install, goes to Recovery(TWRP) and reboots automatically after installation. Otherwise, you need to follow the step of @DeathMaskSalesman

Comment: @RahulGopi yup. Twrp. Anyway, it finally installed on its own. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If the auto install doesn't work you can go to `/data/lineageos_updates` and install the update manually.

Remember to wipe dalvik cache after flash ends.

Updated (thanks to Sup3rHugh): LOS changed the OTA folder from `/data/data/org.lineageos.update/app_updates` to `/data/lineageos_updates`.

Comment: Why does one have to wipe Dalvik?

Comment: It seem that the download folder location has recently changed to /data/lineageos_updates.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: nothing happened other then being send to the TWRP home menu screen. On the Internet, the most seen solution is to manually update from `/data/data/org.lineageos.update/app_updates`, but that didn't work for me, because that directory didn't seem to exist.

My solution was to turn off zip file verification in TWRP and then try it again. Step by step:

1. Go to the LineageOS update screen: `Settings` > `about phone` > `LineageOS updates` > choose to download the update > choose to apply the update.
2. While applying the update, it will reboot the phone in TWRP recovery mode and will send you to the TWRP home menu screen instead of installing the update. Check the log to see what happened: `Advanced` > `Copy Log`> slide to copy > this will not only copy, but also show the log. If you see something in red text with a warning/error like: unable to verify zip, or md5 verification failed or something like that, than you need to turn off zip verification.
3. To disable zip verification: go to the home menu of TWRP > `Settings` > uncheck `Zip signature verification` > and reboot the system.
4. Perform step 1 again, this time it should succeed and install the update automatically after it reboot automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please go to the Settings>about phone>lineageOS update Often
   download    the update long tap the center of update, then selected
   update and    you can select the save icon in top Windows to save to
   card.
2. now go to the Settings>about phone>lineageOS update again and click    to install and reboot your phone automatically.
3. after reboot go to the boot recovery and you can click the install    and selected the zip file and swipe the scroll to install update.